# How to transfer files from S3 Bucket to AWS SQS using .Net Core?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I am trying to create a lambda function to transfer text files from s3 bucket to Amazon SQS using .Net Core. I am able to connect to the bucket, and get the list of files, but not sure how to copy the files.(The file size can be up to 1 GB).

```
string queueURL = "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/1123456/testQueue";
string bucketName = "testbucket";
IAmazonSQS sqsClient = new AmazonSQSClient();

var queueARN = await sqsClient.AuthorizeS3ToSendMessageAsync(queueUrl, bucketName);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queueARN))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"The Amazon S3 bucket: {bucketName} has been successfully authorized.");
    Console.WriteLine($"{bucketName} can now send messages to the queue with ARN: {queueARN}.");
}

ListObjectsResponse objectResponse = await S3Client.ListObjectsAsync(bucketName);

foreach (S3Object files in objectResponse.S3Objects)
{
    var response = await S3Client.GetObjectAsync(bucketName, files.Key);

    //SendMessageResponse responseSendMsg =   await sqsClient.SendMessageAsync(queueUrl, response);
}
```

Can you please provide some samples? Thank you.

Comment: [The maximum SQS message size is 262,144 bytes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/quotas-messages.html).  If you want to send larger messages, you'll need to send references to data stored elsewhere.

Comment: Can I ask... _WHY_ do you want to "transfer files from S3 Bucket to AWS SQS"? What is your actual requirement for having these files in SQS?

Comment: I found a another solution to implement my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As alluded to in the comments the best solution here would be to publish a reference to your S3 object as part of your SQS message body. Your consumer can then use the S3 SDK to read the file.

This is a pretty common pattern for passing large payloads through SQS.